# Any probabalstic benefit to playing in the easier group, if you'll meet the winner of the harder group in the final?

Tags: probability

There's a game with four players, numbered by their increasing difficulty: `1`,`2`,`3` and `4`.

The probability of any player (`x`) beating another player (`y`) in a 1v1 game is `x / (x + y)`. For example if player `3` plays player `4` the chance of player `3` winning is `3/7`. There are no draws - every game ends in one side winning.

There's a tournament where in the first round the four players are organised in to two 1v1 groups (group `A` and group `B`). The winner of each group play each other in the final. The winner of the final wins the tournament.

Player `1` gets to choose who they want to play in the first round. For example they might choose to play the easiest opponent (`2`), and hope that they don't meet the hardest opponent (`4`) in the final.

The possible groupings of the first round are:

```
A: 1v2
B: 3v4
```

Or

```
A: 1v3
B: 2v4
```

Or

```
A: 1v4
B: 2v3
```

And in the final the winner of group `A` will play the winner or group `B`:

```
Final: AvB
```

**Can player `1` increase their chance of winning the tournament through their choice of opponent in the first round?** (And how can I calculate their chances in each scenario?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Informally, team $1$ really wants to avoid $3,4$ so it's better if those two play each other.  At least that way, one of the two tough teams is eliminated.

But let's work it out.

I.  $1$ plays $2$ first.

Then, in order to win the whole match, $1$ needs first to beat $2$, probability $\frac 13$.  Then $1$ needs to beat the winner of $3$ vs $4$, which happens with probability $$\frac 14 \times \frac 37+\frac 15\times \frac 47=\frac {31}{140}$$

Thus the probability that $1$ wins along this path is $$\frac 13\times \frac {31}{140}=\frac {31}{420}\approx \boxed{.0738}$$

II.  $1$ plays $3$ first

A similar computation gives $$\frac 14\times \left( \frac 13\times \frac 26+\frac 15\times \frac 46\right)=\frac {11}{180}=\boxed {.06111\cdots}$$

III.  $1$ plays $4$ first.

We get $$\frac 15\times \left( \frac 13\times \frac 25+\frac 14\times \frac 35\right)=\frac {17}{300}=\boxed {.05666\cdots}$$

Warning:  While straightforward, the above calculations are somewhat error prone.  I advise checking them all carefully.

Comment: FWIW, I independently set up a small spreadsheet that confirms these numbers.

Comment: @DavidK  Thanks!